# Return prompt input

Tags: javascript, string, return, prompt

How to return a string input from a prompt, then log it to the console?

```
var userAnswer = prompt("What is your name?") {
    return userAnswer;
    console.log(userAnswer);
}
```

I'd like to log the name to the console with a simple message such as "Hello [name]!" if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not from within the same function.

`return`ing will end the function immediately.

Either log the value **before** you return or capture the return value of the function you return from and then log the value.

```
function foo() {
    var userAnswer = prompt("What is your name?");
    console.log(userAnswer);
    return userAnswer;
}

foo();
```

or

```
function foo() {
    var userAnswer = prompt("What is your name?");
    return userAnswer;
}

console.log(foo());
```